# Multiple title lines with variable using latex in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, title, interpreter

I want to create the following title in my graph in Matlab:

```
text1 = ['Miss Distance at $$t_{f}= $$ ' num2str(MAT_ArrayRTM{1,end}) 'm'];
text2 = ['Miss Distance at $$t_{f}= $$ ' num2str(MAT_ArrayRTM{2,end}) 'm'];
title({'Planar Trajectories of the Missile and the Target' ...
       text1 ...
       text2}, ...
      'fontweight','bold','fontsize',14,'Interpreter','latex');
```

Basically it should look like 3 lines title where the 2nd and 3rd contain a variable from the simulation.

It works fine when text1 and text2 are just strings, but the moment I use variables I get no title.
How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: Your example works on my Matlab (2016b). You can put the number inside the `$$` of math mode: `text1 = ['Miss Distance at $$t_{f}=  ' num2str(MAT_ArrayRTM{1,end}) '$$ m'];`

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a good idea to use [`sprintf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) for string formatting. In your case

```
titeText = sprintf(['Planar Trajectories of the Missile and the Target\n' ...
                    'Miss Distance at $$t_{f}=%.1f$$ m\n'...
                    'Miss Distance at $$t_{f}=%.1f$$ m'], ...
                    MAT_ArrayRTM{1,end}, MAT_ArrayRTM{2,end});
```

should do the job. `%.1f` here specifies a floating point number with 1 number after the decimal point.